# Why does the locator look semi-transparent in this Dynamic graphic?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want a position a locator on a graphic, and update its position based on the mouse position. Here is some sample code:

```
Show[{
  Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[]}], 
  Graphics[Dynamic[
     With[{pt = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}]}, 
        { If[pt===None, ,Locator[pt^2]], Text[pt, {0,0}, {-1,-1}] }
     ]
  ]]
  }, PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2},{-.2, 1.2}}]
```

The weird thing is that sometimes the locator displays normally, sometimes it displays at what looks like half opacity. It flips from normal to half-opacity as I move the mouse around.

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

I'm using Mathematica 8 on OSX.

Comment: Try removing the `Dynamic` in the inner `Graphics` and put it before `Show`.

Comment: @kguler: That fixes the opacity problem (though it does result in a less smoothly-updating dynamic graphic). Why does it work?

Comment: I am not really sure why it works. Re smooth updating I did not see a difference between the two versions in my system. If having multiple graphics objects displayed with `Show` is not essential, you might use `Dynamic@With[{pt = MousePosition[{"Graphics", Graphics}]}, 
  Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[], If[pt === None, , Locator[pt^2]], 
    Black, Text[pt, {0, 0}, {-1, -1}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-.2, 1.2}, {-.2, 1.2}}]] `